What is the functional derivative of a general composition of functions?
Let $F_{a,b} := f_a\circ f_{a+1} \circ\cdots \circ f_{b-1}\circ f_b$ and $F_N := F_{1,N}$, i.e.
$$F_N(x) = f_1(f_2(\cdots(f_N(x)))\cdots).$$
Then what is
$$\frac{\delta F_N(x)}{\delta f_k(y)}\quad\text{for } k\in\{1,...,N\}?$$
(Note I'm using Physicist notation where $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta f(y)} = \delta(x-y)$ with the latter $\delta$ being the Dirac delta distribution, feel free to multiply with a test function and integrate for a more sound definition inside an actual functional)

Write $$F_N(x) = F_{k-1}(f_k(\underbrace{F_{k+1,N}(x)}_{=:u_k}))$$
(and assume $F_0(x)=x$ for the $k=1$ case) and just apply the chain rule to obtain
$$\frac{\delta F_N(x)}{\delta f_k(y)} = F_{k-1}'(f_k(u_k))\cdot \delta(u_k - y).$$
While this looks simple enough, there are two complications:

$F_{k-1}'$ actually yields a lengthy (but well-defined) product due to the implied chain rule
$\delta(u_k-y)$ implies a weighted summation over all points $x$ that satisfy $F_{k+1,N}(x) = y$ and things become messy singular for $x$ where this is not just a simple root, as I've derived elsewhere

